# Which plugins are required in openfire for working of chat

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am new in iOS, I have successfully login and registered the user, but messages are not working. I have search for some missing plugins but I don't know which plugins are required for enabling/ working of chat.

I have already installed plugins in openfire like: broadcasting,presence,client control etc.

Any sugesstions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have setup a basic part then you need to make a checklist for enabling which plugins you need. After that you need to check that your login, connection, authentication are working or not and make sure that you are using correct domain and port.
If still messages are not receiving then check the delegate method:

```
 func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) { 
  print("message = \(message.body)")
 }
```

By this method you can check the messages are receiving or not.